# Append multiple images to divs using javascript only

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a small script that counts images that I uploaded/inserted to my html source code. After I inserted images script creates div containers for those images. If I gave three images, then script will create three divs with class name etc. I have css rule with that class name. This was create before any images were in that container. Everything works but I just can't append those newly images to newly created divs. Is there a way using JavaScript only?

Here is a code:

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("Multimedia")[0].getElementsByTagName("IMG")) {
    total_number_of_images = document.getElementsByClassName("Multimedia")[0].getElementsByTagName("IMG").length;
    for (i = 0; i < total_number_of_images; i = i + 1) {
        document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[i].className = "Image_clip";
        child = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[i];
        image_container = document.createElement("DIV");
        image_container.className = "Image_container_div";
        document.getElementsByClassName("Multimedia")[0].appendChild(image_container);
        document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")[i].style.opacity = "0.8";
    }

}
```

I tried somthenig like this:

```
image_container.appendChild(child);
```

But then I can get only two images into container... my third is out and also without `className`. Without this code, I get `className` for every image

Comment: please make a jsfiddle, it will help us.

Comment: Hi. I update my fiddle with JavaScript http://jsfiddle.net/Slit/5gkwopwv/1/

Answer (score 0):

You should cache the reference to elements rather than querying `DOM` in loops.
If I understood correctly, Your code should look something like the following for wrapping each image in a container `<div>`:

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("multimedia")[0];
 // if there is only one match, use an id instead ------------^ ?
var images = container.getElementsByTagName("img");
for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  img.className = "imageClip";
  img.style.opacity = "0.8"; // Why not define this in imageClip class ..?
  imageContainer = document.createElement("div");
  imageContainer.className = "imageContainer";
  imageContainer.appendChild(img);
  container.appendChild(imageContainer);
}
```

Comment: Not working for me. Yes I want to wrap images into divs. One image to one div

Answer (score 0):

This I get on Yahoo answer. Posted by YaYox: http://jsfiddle.net/ffxad4bq/4

```
function myFunction() {
    var multimedia = document.getElementsByClassName("Multimedia")[0]
    var imgs = multimedia.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {

        imgs[0].className = "Image_clip";
        imgs[0].style.opacity = "0.3";

        multimedia.innerHTML += '<div class="Image_container_div">'+imgs[0].outerHTML+'</div>';
        imgs[0].remove()

    }

}
```

I realized what was the problem. I shouldn't itaret through images. Just leave it on zero because, when loops start, code append one image at a time. When second loop starts I don't have any more 3 images, but two, that is why one image always stays out because loop goes three times.

---